# Twitter Feed on console using Ampersand.js?

Tags: node.js, twitter, ampersand.js

I am trying to create a simple application that streams tweets using the Twit module in node and prints them to the web console. Have followed the Ampersand.js docs word to word so far.

My Directory structure is :

```
TwitterLiveFeed/app.bundle.js

TwitterLiveFeed/app.js

TwitterLiveFeed/index.html

TwitterLiveFeed/streamtweets.js

TwitterLiveFeed/package.json

TwitterLiveFeed/node_modules/browserify

TwitterLiveFeed/node_modules/twit
```

Here's the code :

streamtweets.js (module)

```
// twitterlivefeed/streamtweets.js

//require the twit npm module
var Twit = require('twit');


function streamTweets() {
    var T = new Twit({
        consumer_key:         '---'
      , consumer_secret:      '---        
      , access_token:         '---'
      , access_token_secret:  '---'
   })

    var stream = T.stream('statuses/sample')

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      console.log(tweet)
    })
}

//export streamTweets as the module function

module.exports=streamTweets;
```

app.js

```
// ./twitterlivefeed/app.js

console.log("Welcome!")

// require the local module

var streamTweets=require('./streamtweets.js');

// calling function

streamTweets();
```

Then I run "./node_modules/.bin/browserify app.js -o app.bundle.js" to compile the application down to a single file

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
  <script src='app.bundle.js'></script>
```

When I run index.html on the browser, it just prints 'Welcome'. I can see the 'Total Size of all Resources' tab on Error Console in Safari keep increasing in size, so I am sure the code's doing something. Just unable to get any output.

Help?

**EDIT 1 :**

So I edited my module code to this and it works.

```
var Twit = require('twit');

function streamTweets() {    

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})

var options = { screen_name: 'username',
                count: 3 };

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', options , function(err, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].text);
  }
})
```

Why does the above code work and stream not work?

Comment: So, with browserify, you want to be able to receive the tweets in the browser, or how should I understand this? I doubt that this works...

Comment: With browserify, I am just bundling the application down to a single file. I am able to output tweets when using get('statuses/user_timeline'), but doesn't work when I try to stream. Why would that be the case?

Comment: Check EDIT 1 for example of working code for above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Twitter docs:

- https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting

> Establishing a connection to the streaming APIs means making a very long lived HTTP request, and parsing the response incrementally. Conceptually, you can think of it as downloading an infinitely long file over HTTP.

I think this generally disqualifies the browser as and endpoint "host" for streams. A much better solution would be to open a connection in the Node.js backend, and send the stream to the client(s) via WebSockets or socket.io

There are numerous tutorials on this:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-and-react-js
- http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/node-js-twitter-streaming-api-socket-io-twitter-cashtag-heatmap/
- http://ikertxu.tumblr.com/post/56686134143/nodejs-socketio-and-the-twitter-streaming-api